# I need to apply extract only matched pattern and do some operations by using mathed files

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Here I am providing array variable :

```
arryFilePrefix=('State','Statement','Sense','Senseful','view_Model')
```

And I am having some list of files which mentioned below, so I need to extract matching files from those list of files:

Here I am providing some list of files :

```
$ls home/fileScript

State_6721_4568
State_8888_9999
Statement_1231_2369
Sense_1231_2369
Sense_1231_5678
Senseful_3453_2211
view_Model_1212_1111
view_Model_1231_2369
view_Model_8521_4421
```

I need to apply loop and grep so that for each loop turn I can extract matched one.

I tried with this below code :

```
arryFilePrefix=('State','Statement','Sense','Senseful','view_Model')

for arg in "${arryFilePrefix[@]}";

do 

var=$(ls home/fileScript | grep "^$arg"); 

echo "$arg matched files are : $var"

done
```

But the output is :

```
State matched files are :    
State_1231_2369    
State_6721_4568    
State_8888_9999    
Statement_1231_2369

Statement matched files are :    
Statement_1231_2369

Sense matched files are :     
Sense_1231_2369    
Sense_1231_5678    
Senseful_3453_2211

Senseful matched files are :     
Senseful_3453_2211

view_Model matched files are :     
view_Model_1212_1111    
view_Model_1231_2369    
view_Model_8521_4421
```

If we observe above output which was I got is Statement and Senseful are also came in State and Sense matched files which actually not correct.

So Please help in this how can I extract only matched files from given list of files.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax of array declaration is:

```
arryFilePrefix=('State' 'Statement' 'Sense' 'Senseful' 'view_Model')
```

and use it as:

```
for arg in "${arryFilePrefix[@]}"; do
    printf '\n%s matched files are :\n' "$arg"
    printf '%s\n' /home/fileScript/"${arg}_"*
done
```

**Output:**

```
State matched files are :
/home/fileScript/State_6721_4568
/home/fileScript/State_8888_9999

Statement matched files are :
/home/fileScript/Statement_1231_2369

Sense matched files are :
/home/fileScript/Sense_1231_2369
/home/fileScript/Sense_1231_5678

Senseful matched files are :
/home/fileScript/Senseful_3453_2211

view_Model matched files are :
/home/fileScript/view_Model_1212_1111
/home/fileScript/view_Model_1231_2369
/home/fileScript/view_Model_8521_4421
```

Comment: printf '\n%s matched files are :' "$arg"
    printf '%s\n' ./"${arg}_"* here you are not extract all files from given folder home/fileScript right, then how can I extract matching files without thos all list of files.

Comment: yeah. it is working, that is i know but requirement is execute sh file from home directory, but sh file is there in different folder. But it is also working thanks @anubhava for giving solution

Comment: You can see edited script that can run from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as following :
1. Define the array as suggested by Anubhava
2. Just change the grep command from `grep "^$arg"` to `grep "^$arg[_]"`. (As your filenames have `_` after the initials.)

Rest of your original code is fine and it should work as expected.

Below is your original code with the suggested changes along with Output:

```
arryFilePrefix=('State' 'Statement' 'Sense' 'Senseful' 'view_Model')
for arg in "${arryFilePrefix[@]}";
do
var=$(ls home/fileScript | grep "^$arg[_]");
echo -e "$arg matched files are :\n$var\n"  # -e enables escape characters (here for \n)
done
```

Output:

```
State matched files are :
State_6721_4568
State_8888_9999
Statement matched files are :
Statement_1231_2369
Sense matched files are :
Sense_1231_2369
Sense_1231_5678
Senseful matched files are :
Senseful_3453_2211
view_Model matched files are :
view_Model_1212_1111
view_Model_1231_2369
view_Model_8521_4421
```

Comment: here I tried with your grep code but I was getting all files including not matched files also..

Comment: @EdMorton : Thanks. Removed -P and also corrected _ as per your suggestions.

Comment: The correct syntax for referencing a variable `$arg` in a longer string is `${arg}_`, not `$arg[_]`. That latter only "works" because `_` is a single non-meta character, if it was more (e.g. `foo` instead of `_`) you'd have to write `$arg[f]oo` instead of the clearer `${arg}foo` and you couldn't use it at all if it was a globbing or regexp metacharacter (e.g. `${arg}.` vs `$arg[.]`). I actually thought you were trying to use it as an array at first!

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks again. I'd actually used `grep -P  "^$arg[_]"` before last edit where `[_]` was part of the regex and was explicitly mentioned within character class. After your suggestions I'd removed -P but didn't change `[_]`. But yes the  way would be ${arg}  in cases where it is actually required in longer strings. Correct me if m wrong.